# MSI build through octopus

Tags: wix, wix3.6, octopus-deploy

I have generated an MSI using Wix for the deployment we used octopus. While running the msi build through octopus some files like dlls, .. are not getting updated in the respective path for the first time of deployment. If we install the same for second time then works fine all the files placed in the folder.

These are the steps I have followed:

I have created a Wix project and generated a msi build through that. Then through the octopus using .xml file I have deployed the content in the specified folder. And deployment was not successful through octopus.

Answer (score 2):

You really haven't given any information to troubleshoot.  Are you using major upgrades or minor upgrades?  What's your command line?  Have you logged the installers and read through the logs?   What do they tell you?

```
msiexec /i example.msi /qn /l*v install.log
```

/qn = silent /l*v = verbose logging

My first suspect is that you aren't versioning your DLL's correctly and that Windows Installer is skipping over them.  Please see:

[File Versioning Rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599(v=vs.85).aspx)
[Default File Versioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368267(v=vs.85).aspx)
[Replacing Existing Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371221(v=vs.85).aspx)